# jquery mobile load event that is equal to window.load event over the timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, jquery-mobile

Using jquery mobile 1.1.0 many devices can have diffrent sceen height, to fill empty space im doing:
content_height = screen_height - header_height - footer_height

The only event that will really wait untill everything is loaded to calc the real height is

```
$(window).load
```

my problem: becuase im using the ajax navigating system,  window.load will fire only once and i tested many load staging events:

```
$(document).bind('pagechange', func..)
$(document).bind('pageload', func..)
```

and so on..

my question: is there a jquery mobile event that will fire on every page load and late enough for sizes to load? or any other way to triger a method when content is loaded.

Comment: Did you found the solution?, here is an example of events fired by jquerymobile: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/CAtWG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/CAtWG/

If you want to do stuff when pages are fully loaded:
in your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    //$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
    // set global config of jquery mobile here
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='test.js'></script>
```

then put in your test.js file:

```
$("#Mypage1").live("pagecreate", function() {
     //do stuff when Mypage1 is created 
     // happens once if you don't explicitly refresh
      alert("Mypage1 created");
     $("#mydiv").height($("body").height() - 50);
});

$("#Mypage1").live("pageshow", function() {
     //do stuff when Mypage1 is shown
     // happens multiple times, as soon as you go to Mypage1 from other pages
     alert("Mypage1 visible");
});
```

you are probably also looking for orientation changes event, thus add:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', _orientationHandler);

if(event.orientation){
    if(event.orientation == 'portrait'){
              //do something
    }
    else if(event.orientation == 'landscape') {
                //do something
    }
}
```

If you triggered yourself an ajax request, and want to modify html, simply do in the callback:

```
$("#Mypage1").trigger("pagecreate");
```